# What happened to the Borg ship that attacked the outposts in the neutral zone?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

We know that the Borg were already right by the Federation and Romulan space in the episode called “The Neutral Zone” in season 1. I know changes were made to the Borg later due to the writers' strike, but was there any mention of where that Borg ship was after that?  Did it return to Borg space?  Did it just go into low power mode until it was time to attack?  Was it the ship they ended up fighting in BOBW 1 and 2?

Comment: do we indeed *know* that it was the Borg in the Neutral Zone and not the parasite creatures from "Conspiracy"? I believe it is true that it was retconned (either fan-retcon or official I don't know) that it was the Borg

Comment: It was later mention that it was indeed the Borg and that was confirmed by a magnetic resonance signature left in the destroyed outposts.

Comment: @NKCampbell interestingly, the "Conspiracy" creatures were going to be revealed to be an advance infiltration for the Borg, but the writers decided to not make that connection.

Comment: yes as a retcon @JesseC.Slicer